# Prevent Flutter debugger changing URL?

Tags: flutter

Whenever I run my Flutter app with `c:/data/flutter/bin/flutter run -d chrome --web-hostname localhost --web-port 60308` the URL of the app remains constant, at `http://localhost:60308/#/`.

But the Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler URL of the app keeps changing, and I have to copy and paste it from the command line every single time. How do I make this URL remain constant too please?

Answer (score 0):

Follow (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code#run-app-in-debug-profile-or-release-mode)

```
  "configurations": [{
    "name": "Flutter",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart",
    "flutterMode": "debug"
    "args": [
      "--web-port",
      "60308"
    ]
  }]
```